# Flash hyperlink - changing var name in url

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hyperlink

I have trouble with hyperlink in flash on site. As site is in CMS, with different
stages of approval I do not know exact url, so

```
function piClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  var url:String = "/cms__Main?name=Target_name";
  var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
  try {
    navigateToURL(request, '_self');
  } catch (e:Error) {
    trace("Error occurred!");
  }
}
```

does not work, as cms_Main changes according to stage of site. What I probably need to do is:

- grab url (or part after last "/" if that is even possible)
- change "name" variable inside String

f.e

```
https://domain_name/.../status?name=Name_I_need_to_swap&sname=Country_name&..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stage.loaderInfo.url` will get you the address of the swf itself so it won't get you the full address, the query or the hash tag. You can, however, grab all this information using Javascript.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function getFullAddress():String {
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        var href:String = ExternalInterface.call('function(){return window.location.href}');
        if (href) return href.toString();
    }
    throw new Error('Make sure JS is enabled.');
}
var fullAddr:String = getFullAddress();
```

**EDIT:** Here's how you can get and modify all that you're asking.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;


function getFullAddress():String {
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        var href:String = ExternalInterface.call('function(){return window.location.href}');
        if (href) return href.toString();
    }
    throw new Error('Make sure JS is enabled.');
}
function getQuery(fullAddr:String):URLVariables {
    if (!fullAddr.match(/\?[^#]/)) return new URLVariables();
    var q:String = fullAddr.replace(/^.*?\?([^#]+)(#.*)?$/,'$1');
    return new URLVariables(q);
}
function getAddress(fullAddr:String):String {
    return fullAddr.replace(/\?.*/,'').replace(/#.*/,'');
}
function getRequest(url:String,query:URLVariables=null,method:String='GET'):URLRequest {
    method = URLRequestMethod[method] || 'GET';
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    req.method = method;
    if (method == 'GET' && query != null) {
        req.url += '?' + query.toString().replace(/%5f/gi,'_').replace(/%2d/gi,'-');
        // this is because dash and underscore chars are also
        // encoded by URLVariables. we want to omit this.
        return req;
    }
    req.data = query;
    return req;
}


var fullAddr:String = getFullAddress();
var addr:String = getAddress(fullAddr);

var query:URLVariables = getQuery(fullAddr);
query.name = 'Name_I_need_to_swap';
query.sname = 'Country_name';
// add as many variable-value pairs as you like
// and don't worry, they will be automatically
// encoded by the function called below

var req:URLRequest = getRequest(addr,query);
//navigateToURL(req);

// check the console to see the changed address
ExternalInterface.call('console.log',req);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get URL with `this.loaderInfo.url`